# D3 spaces between groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I add some padding between groups in a grouped bar chart?

I have 2 groups and 5 categories on the x axis. Im trying to get some padding between the pairs ([group1, group2,] space, [group1, group2], etc.) I tried with rangeBand(), with the scale, etc. but its not working.

Any suggestions?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/u06xk6wj/)

Relevant samples of the code:

```
var values = feature.properties;              
var data = [
    {name:"NoDipOL",value:values["NoDipOL"]},
    {name:"NoDipNOL",value:values["NoDipNOL"]},
    {name:"HSOL",value:values["HSOL"]},
    {name:"HSNOL",value:values["HSNOL"]},
    {name:"ColOL",value:values["ColOL"]},
    {name:"ColNOL",value:values["ColNOL"]},
    {name:"UnOL",value:values["UnOL"]},
    {name:"UnNOL",value:values["UnNOL"]}
];

var Colors =  ["#a6cee3", "#1f78b4"];
var ColorNames = ["Group1", "Group2"];

[...] 

// Scale for x and y axis
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["No diploma", "High school", "College", "University"])
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.value;})])
    .range([height, 0]);

//Ordinal x axis. 
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0);

[...]

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * barWidth;})
    .attr("width", barWidth - 1 )
    .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) {return height - y(d.value);})
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return Colors[i % 2]; }); //Alternate colors

bar.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.value) - 5; })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * barWidth;})
    .attr("dx", barWidth / 2)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "14px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
```

Comment: Should we see a chart in the jsfiddle you linked? I just see a map of North America.

Comment: I adjusted the view to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `rangeBand` to place your ticks but you don't use it to size and place your rects.  First fix the data so it can use the `rangeBand`:

```
var data = [
    {name:"No diploma",value:values["NoDipOL"]},
    {name:"No diploma",value:values["NoDipNOL"]},
    {name:"High school",value:values["HSOL"]},
    {name:"High school",value:values["HSNOL"]},
    {name:"College",value:values["ColOL"]},
    {name:"College",value:values["ColNOL"]},
    {name:"University",value:values["UnOL"]},
    {name:"University",value:values["UnNOL"]}
];
```

Then place your rects:

```
bar.append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { 
        return (i % 2 === 0) ? // every other bar
            x(d.name) : // if even place at start of band
            x(d.name) + x.rangeBand()/2; // if odd (second bar) move it over
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand()/2 )  // and width is half the rangeband
    ...
```

Updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/u06xk6wj/206/).

Comment: Mark, I was trying to use rangeBand() to place the rects but it wasnt working. I was getting overlapping bars. I never thought of changing how the data is defined. That function you did on "x" is new to me. Thank you!

Comment: @Monduiz, you have an ordinal scale, `x` (which is a function) with a domain of `["No diploma", "High school", "College", "University"]`, `x(d.name)` is simply calling your scale function passing in a domain location, `x('College')`, this returns the corresponding pixel x position on the scale.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I appreciate it!